# Getting can't convert undefined to object while reading from json file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, highcharts

**Scenario** :

- A json file
- Read json data and plot graph using highcharts

**Problem**: Getting `can't convert undefined to object` when loading html without breakpoint in mozilla firefox.

- When loading with a breakpoint the graph is getting perfectly plotted.
- without breakpoint, getting `myjson` as undefined in function `chartFormyJson`

**Code** :
I have a node project and I am starting `http server` using `npm run serve`.

`Index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="scriptFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`scriptFile.js`

```
var myjson;
fetch('./data.json').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    myjson=data["myjson"];
})

if( document.readyState !== 'loading' ) {
    console.log( 'document is already ready, just execute code here' );
    chartFormyJson();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log( 'document was not ready, place code here' );
        chartFormyJson();
    });
}

function chartFormyJson(){
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Plot bar graph per year'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: Object.keys(myjson)
    },
    series: [{
        data: Object.values(myjson)
    }]
});
}
```

Need guidance in why it happening this way.Seems something related with loading of data/variables/order of call to js from html.But I am not an expert on these so will really appreciate any help on this.

Let me know if any further info is needed.

Comment: You are waiting for the document to load - great. But that is not waiting for the `fetch()` request to complete - bummer. Run `chartFormyJson()` in the second `then()` of `fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked .. also wanted to know if there is any way to execute `fetch() ` async..so that when `fetch()` is ready it calls `chartFormyJson()`..but all async..if it can be done in JS can u please point me to some resource/link

Comment: I don't understand your follow-on question about async. The entire operation of `fetch()` is asynchronous. That is where the `.then()` methods come from. Do something _then_ (eventually, whenever the async activity is complete) do something else. You can make it _feel_ more synchronous by using [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).